# Angular: Live update with SignalR behind the proxy webserver

Tags: c#, web-applications, proxy, signalr

I am using SignalR in order to update my dashboard page. This page developed by Angular 5 and web Api. For security purpose, My angular application sends it API requests to a small web application that act as a proxy server and change the port to the actual API server.

My proxy server is running on port 7030 and API server on port 7050.

My SignalR Hub is also running on the API server. In my Angular page, if I connect to the hub through port 7050 (API Server), It works fine and It will update as soon as any changes occurred in the database. But if I change the connection to port 7030 (Proxy server) It gives the WebSocket handshake error and after browsing different pages it becomes slow and almost after 20 seconds it reflects the database changes!

> WebSocker connection to 'ws://localhost:7030/signalr/connect?transport=webSockets&clientProtocol=1.5&connectionToken=&connectionData=&tid=4' failed
>   WebSocket handshake: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

This is the code that I am using as port srcipt handler in my proxy web application :

```
protected override async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var scheme = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Scheme"];
    var host = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Host"];
         int port;
    int.TryParse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Port"], out port);

    var forwardUri = new UriBuilder(request.RequestUri)
    {

        Scheme = scheme,
        Host = host,
        Port = port
    };

    System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =
                ((sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true);

    request.RequestUri = forwardUri.Uri;           
    request.Headers.Host = host;

    var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    return response;
}
```

And this problem only exists while I am using HTTP protocol. As soon as I browse my website by https, The SignalR works fine!